# Perl Chart::Gnuplot - access ASCII output of plot2d

Tags: perl, plot, gnuplot

I'm using the Perl module Chart::Gnuplot to produce some ASCII plots with `terminal 'dumb'`.

Instead of having the function plot2d directly print the plot results I would like to capture the nicely formatted ASCII plot in a temporary variable so I can print it later.

Here is a MWE of what I'm doing, showing what works and what does not.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Chart::Gnuplot;

my @xvals=(1...10);
my @yvals=(1...10);


my $chart = Chart::Gnuplot->new( 
    terminal=>'dumb',
    xrange => [0, 10], 
    yrange => [0, 10], 
);

my $dataset = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new(
    style => "dots",    
    xdata => \@xvals,
    ydata => \@yvals

);

$chart->plot2d($dataset);                  # This works


my $textplot = $chart->plot2d($dataset);   # This does not work, nor did I expect it to
print($textplot);                          # Prints a hash ref like "Chart::Gnuplot=HASH(0x6000cbb80)"
```

As I mentioned, I didn't expect plot2d to directly output the plot, but I'm wondering if there is some method/function/whatever that would allow me to do this. Can I tell plot2d to plot to a string variable instead of STDOUT?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll see if the solution discussed there works for me. One challenge for me is the script I'm writing gets called by another main script which is handling STDIN/OUT so all the printing etc I do is to a logfile using functions provided by that main script. This has some weird effects in practice, e.g. if I use <STDIN> to pause for a keyhit, it locks up the main script. That's why I was hoping to get the output of plot2d in some way other than messing around with STDIN/OUT redirection.

Comment: Never mind, I was wrong. ikegami's answer is way simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a temporary file (say using [File::Temp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Temp)) and pass its path to the constructor's `output` option. You can collect the output from that temporary file.

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising! I didn't realize you could set the output file to a text file, but it appears to work if you're using `terminal dumb`. I'll do some experimenting and see if I hit any problems.

Comment: Yup, that worked great. Also for anyone else doing this, if you're not worried about multiple instances of your script fighting over the same file, you can use the built in `time` function to get a fairly unique timestamp and use that as a filename.

Comment: Or use File::Temp as I suggested. It will also ensure the temporary file gets erased if possible. F::T is core, and is even used by Chart::Gnuplot